# WIX run second application then first is done

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, burn

I stuck on problem with wix installer. My idea is create .msi installer, and then user install .msi , the setup.exe runs , and then user close this setup.exe(setup will install microsoft add-in) the second one(picture) will be opened sequently. Now this code below runs after checkbox is ticked two aplications both at once. Is the way to run picture only when closed first one ? Please suggest! Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="b288bcab-ad20-47d5-8d2c-1111111111" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Language="1033" Name="Program" Manufacturer="Program LTD">
    <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" /> 
    <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" />

    <!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="InstallFiles" Name="Launch Program">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

  <!-- set property and launch the first exe -->
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="PrepareLaunchApplication1">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication1">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>

  <!-- set property and launch the second exe -->
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="PrepareLaunchApplication2">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication2">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Program" />

<CustomAction Id="PrepareLaunchApplication1" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#Setup.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication1"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" 
    Return="check"
    Execute="immediate"/>

<CustomAction Id="PrepareLaunchApplication2" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#picture.png]" />  
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication2" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="no"
   />

    <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="InstallFiles">
      <Component Id="Setup.exe">
        <File Id="Setup.exe" KeyPath="yes"
              Name="Setup.exe" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>
 <Component Id="picture.png">
        <File Id="picture.png" KeyPath="yes"
              Name="picture.png" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>  
    </DirectoryRef>


    <!-- Step 3: Tell WiX to install the files -->
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">

      <ComponentRef Id="Setup.exe" />
      <ComponentRef Id="picture.png" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kicking off installs using custom actions is a very ill-advised endeavor. It is likely to cause you only problems, and it is just not good design.

Running installers in sequence is what the **WiX's bootstrapper feature [Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)** is for - it allows you to run MSI files and EXE files in a specified sequence.

I believe you can find a working sample of how Burn works here: https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme. Essentially it is a different type of WiX source file with its own schema designed for bootstrapper creation.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for answer Stein , very interesting idea. Maybe you know is it possible to run exe after mai finish installation and run exe file , and then exe is closed after it run for example wellcome window? And if it possible what is the best practice? I mean best way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrej Some features are better implemented in the application rather than in an installer. What you describing sounds like a typical "splash screen" dialog or first-run feature. Your setup could launch the application with an argument telling it why is it being launched—with an appropriate handler coded into the application.

Comment: Yes, I probably didn't look properly at your code. What is in your setup.exe? Is it a third party software? And what are you trying to achieve overall. What is that picture?