# Wix installer execute a cmd with parameters

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer

I have a requirement to run a command silently as part of an install routine.

The command I need to run is as follows:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\MPSAuditTool\v1\mrt.exe" /s /v"cmd=silent"
```

Now the end part I know is causing an issue trying to pass it through a normal exe command with the quotation characters. My various google searches have led me to try using VBS to achieve this now.

My vbs

```
Public Function runQuiet()
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run("cmd.exe c:\Program Files (x86)\MPSAuditTool\v1\mrt.exe /s /v"), 0 
Set oShell = Nothing
End Function
```

My WiX code for reference:

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SilentMRT" After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

<Binary Id="SilentInstall" SourceFile="E000874\launchquiet.vbs" />
<CustomAction BinaryKey="SilentInstall" VBScriptCall="runQuiet" Id="SilentMRT" Return="check" />
```

The installer runs correctly but the mrt.exe is not run at all. When I remove the `,0` and the `oShell=Nothing` lines, a cmd prompt is displayed but it doesn't call the .exe, it just pops a prompt up.

If I run the VBS from a cmd using wScript it runs the exe silently as expected.

Any thoughts on what I need to change in the vbs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run programs with too many spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649265/run-programs-with-too-many-spaces)

Comment: Does this command require any elevation? Do you get a UAC prompt when you try to run it interactively? Also: what tool is this, what is it doing? Just trying to understand what could conspire.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul If I run the command in an admin window, I don't get a UAC prompt. The tool is an applicaiton we are installing on a users' pc. The /s /v are triggers to install the .exe silently

Comment: See some comments below. I hope I have understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What does the log files say? Don't launch MSI installs from custom actions inside other MSI files. Two concurrent MSI sessions are not allowed technically. Instead, **use a bootstrapper** - such as [**WiX's Burn feature**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48996357/129130) - to run the setups one after the other. It is not that hard to implement, and you will save yourself a lot of trouble. [Burn documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). Seriously: it should solve all your problems, and no custom actions or VBScripts are necessary.

Launching another MSI with an immediate mode custom action after InstallFinalize (like you seem to do) will also fail because the custom action will not run with elevated rights (when launched silently). So even if the previous MSI session has ended at InstallFinalize, it still fails due to other technical restrictions than the one mentioned above (two concurrent session objects not allowed).

For the record: the MSI session (change transaction) runs between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize - just mentioning it - it is a long story. Elevated custom actions must all be placed between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

All immediate mode custom actions after InstallFinalize that modify the system is by definition wrong. Frankly there should be no custom actions at all after InstallFinalize. They will always run without elevation, and they will always be without rollback support. Deferred custom actions here will fail to compile.

And please don't try to put the custom action in the UI sequence - this will cause it to never run when the setup is installed silently.